# Increment number in string in JS

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex, but it does not do what I expect:

```
name.replace(/sor\s*(\d+)\.\s*szék/, function () {
  return arguments[1] * 1 + 1;
});
```

My string is `1. sor 1. szék`. And I would expect a return `1. sor 2. szék`

but the return value is: `1. 2`. Why?

Comment: Note that your code currently replaces the entire match, as it's supposed to; not just the first group. Also, note that the regex replace function actually [has an argument list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter), no need to use `arguments`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simplify the regular experession and replace only the second occurence of digits with an incremented value.

```js
const
    string = '1. sor 1. szék.',
    result = string.replace(/\d+/g, (c => v => c-- ? v : +v + 1)(1));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the value `1. 2` as the pattern `sor\s*(\d+)\.\s*szék` does not match the leading `1.`  so that will be untouched.

The part `arguments[1] * 1` is 1, and then you add 1 to it resulting in 2.

---

If you want to use replace, you can use 3 capture groups and use those in the replacement, passing the group parameters to the callback function of replace.

The captured digits are in group 2, and to prevent concatenating 2 strings you can add a `+` before group 2.

```js
let name = "1. sor 1. szék";
name = name.replace(
  /(sor\s*)(\d+)(\.\s*szék)/,
  (m, g1, g2, g3) => `${g1}${+g2+1}${g3}`
);
console.log(name);
```

Comment: Alternatively, no need for adding more groups and recomposing in this specific case, `(full, num) => full.replace(num, +num + 1)` would probably work just fine. Although if you are going to use more capture groups, don't use `+` for the string concatenation, use template literals instead so that there's no confusion about what the plus symbol does: ```return `${g1}${+g2+1}${g3}`;```

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thanks for the comment, the template literal is a good tip, also the shortened function syntax.